# Learning Chinese using traditional characters

Tags: writing, books

I believe in Taiwan people use traditional Chinese characters for writing whereas in China they use simplified characters. Assuming this information is correct I'd like to kindly request suggestions for good textbooks teaching Chinese using traditional characters. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yup, both Taiwan and Hong Kong use traditional characters, and many of the characters in Japanese which come from Chinese characters are also traditional. As for finding a text book, I believe most decent Mandarin textbooks nowadays have all the vocabulary, dialogs, and examples in both simplified and traditional, some are essentially the same book printed twice with traditional on every left page and simplified on the right.

Comment: @QuestionMarks Ooh! Thank you! I didn't know that. In this case I can take any textbook with good reviews :-)

Comment: If you order it online, it should say whether it has one or both forms. For example: [This book](http://www.cheng-tsui.com/store/products/integrated_chinese/integrated_chinese_level_1_part_1_textbook_3rd_edition_traditional) and [this book](http://www.cheng-tsui.com/store/products/integrated_chinese/integrated_chinese_level_2_part_1_textbook_3rd_edition_simplified_0). Higher level books tend to have both, but it should always state it on the cover of the book.

Answer (score 3):

Learning the characters is mostly a matter of memorization. You will need to learn a lot of characters in the most efficient way possible. Textbooks are not good for this. Using a spaced repetition system is normally the best method. A free spaced repetition program is Anki (http://ankisrs.net). You can find "decks" of traditional characters within Anki to start learning.

A pay version of Anki that lets you write the characters stroke by stroke is [Skritter](http://www.skritter.com). I personally like Skritter and have been using it for several years. I find writing out the character helps me to remember it.

To supplement the learning of characters you are going to want to get some form of grammar textbook. I like Ross's "Modern Mandarin Chinese Grammar."